# Filtering Dataframe based on values of two columns, using dictionary(for condition)

Tags: python-3.x, dataframe

I have a dataframe and a dictionary for conditioning rules.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"var_1":["HEMA", "CHEM", "URIN", "HEMA", "CHEM", "URIN"],
                  "var_2":["HGB", "HGB", "HGB", "PH", "PH", "PH"]
                  })

condition = {"HEMA":["HGB","HCT","MONO"],
         "CHEM":["BASO","MCH"],
         "URIN":["PH","SG"]}
```

I want to filter the `df` using `condition` as a condtion.
To be specific, I want to see `df`'s rows where `var_2` an element of `var_1` according to `condition`.

e.g. the first row with `HEMA` and `HGB` is good to show since `HGB` is one of an element of `HEMA` in `condition`.
But the second row with `CHEM` and `HGB` should be filtered out since `CHEM` in `condition` doesn't have `HGB` as an element.

Eventually, `df` should show this data

```
  var_1 var_2
0  HEMA   HGB
1  URIN    PH
```

I tried to use np.where but seems like it's not a right way to use it.
I browsed other solutions, like DataFrame.filter but seems like those are not a right way since of my specific conditions.

The solution with potential is to use query, but I want to use it as plan Z since I don't know much about how it works, and I prefer the simpler solution if there is a way.

Enlighten me please. Thanks.